# Raspberry Pi to Samsung TV to windows 10 (home)

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi

I have bought a Samsung smart TV and planning to permanently have my laptop wireless be mirrored as one of the source to tv.

I am planning to hide raspberry Pi behind the tv to remote access the laptop all the times and display laptop on tv.

How is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use TeamViewer. It is totally free for personal use. TeamViewer Server can allow remote access to devices at all times. It is also cross-platform, so you can use it on Windows, MacOS, iOS, Android, Raspberry Pi, and more.